# Determinant of a Matrix using Gauss Elimination, inconsistent answers

Tags: matrices, determinant, gaussian-elimination

I have worked through finding the determinant of the following Matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
3 & 3 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 8 & 6 \\
2 & 3 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and I have noticed that when I do gaussian elimination the way that I am used to, I always get the wrong answer. Now I don't want to sound cocky, but I don't believe I am performing the elimination incorrectly, as when I use the same method in other applications; solving linear systems of equations; it works out. Am I interpreting the rules of gaussian elimination to find determinants incorrectly?

For example, the first step that I would take for this question, and the general format that I do gaussian elimination would be to replace row 2 with $$ R_2 = 2R_2 -R_1 $$
In other words my general way of doing gaussian elimination is by taking the row I am going to be replacing, multiplying it by a multiple and subtracting it by the pivot row.

I have also attempted the problem a different way (after seeing some other gaussian elimination examples) and used this style
$$ R_2=-\frac 12R_1+R_2$$

This latter style of doing gaussian elimination gave the correct answer, but that is my question, why? Are both methods not linear combinations? And I am aware of the 3 rules that govern gaussian elimination with regards to finding determinants that state

1. If you swap two rows you must multiply the determinant by (-)
2. If you multiply a row by a scalar you must multiply the determinant by that scalar value
3. The linear combination of rows do not change the determinant

So I have made sure to not use the first two rules to rule out any mistakes regarding that, so again I am left scratching my head a bit.

Thank you and sorry for the long write up.

*I have also included pictures showing my full workings with both "styles"*

[Gaussian Elimination Using "my style"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVQQr.jpg)

[Gaussian Elimination Using "proper style?"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c6cM.jpg)

Comment: Each time you multiply a row by a number you must divide the determinant by that number. In your First approach you are multiplying rows by numbers. In your second you are not.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just went through my first approach and divided my determinant by the multiples like you said and it worked out. I am not going to lie, I am still a bit confused by this, as to me I'm also multiplying a row by a number in the second approach, but I guess I'm looking at it the wrong way. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the way I am going to interpret this is that, in the first attempt I am multiplying the row I am changing by a multiple, while the second attempt I am multiplying a row that I am simply using to change a different row.

Comment: Think of $2R_2-R1$ in two steps. You are multiplying $R_2$ by 2 first, which changes the determinant. Then you are subtracting $R_1$ which does not. In your second approach you are not multiplying $R_2$ by anything before you subtract $\frac{1}{2}R_1$. You could multiply $R_1$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ before you subtract it from $R_2$. Then you would need to multiply the determinant by 2 as you have changed the matrix as before.